# can i insert string after "this" inside onclick in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

newbie asking here.

i have an ordered list of multi dimensional array

```
$blok = array
   (
       array("B","X","X",3,4,5,"X",7,8,9,10),
       array("G",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
       array("L",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
       array("Q",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
   );
```

and then i echo each and every array value into separate div :

*already figured it out how to echo them and insert them into div id.

---

---

**my question is : can i insert string after "this" inside onclick ?**

```
<div class="span4"><div class="table1" style="float:left; background-color:magenta;" id= "'. //ARRAY VALUE// .'" onclick="select(this,"B");" >
```

```
<div class="span4"><div class="table1" style="float:left; background-color:blue;" id= "'. //ARRAY VALUE// .'" onclick="select(this,"Q");" >
```

my goal is to input the **div id** (the array value) and the **string** into my database using **input type=hidden** after **onclick**

```
<input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="table"  name="table" value="" />
```

any help is appreciated, i'm drawing a blank here.

---

---

btw this is my javascript :

```
var i=0;    document.getElementById("table").value="";    function select(id , tipe){
if($(id).attr('class')=="table2"){
    $(id).attr('class','table1');
    var m=document.getElementById("table").value.split(",");
    var removeItem = $(id).attr('id');;
    var n = jQuery.grep(m, function(value) {
      return value != removeItem;
    });
    document.getElementById("table").value=n;

    if(n.length==0){i=0;}
}else{
    $(id).attr('class','table2');
    if(i==0){
        document.getElementById("table").value+=$(id).attr('id');
        i=1;
    }else{
        var j=document.getElementById("table").value.split(",");    
        if(jQuery.inArray($(id).attr('id'), j)==-1)         {
            document.getElementById("table").value+=","+$(id).attr('id');
        }
    }   
}
var type=document.getElementById('type');
type.value=tipe   }
```

---

edit : i forgot to mention i'm using concatenation assignment like this :

```
$number  =' <div class="table1" style="float:left; background-color:magenta;" id= "'. $blok[$row][$col] .'" onclick="select(this,"B");" > ';    
$number  .= $blok[$row][$col]; //echo the array value to display the table number
$number  .=' </div> ';
```

so to display those div with ARRAY VALUE as **div id** and **text to display**
i only wrote :

```
echo $number;
```

Comment: Since your select function has two arguments, you an pass two values.
why don't you alert it?

Comment: it even can't run the "change class table1 into table2" function before the alert i try to assign for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the second argument into a single quotes:

```
.. onclick="select(this,'B');" ...
```

for your php code:

```
.'" onclick="select(this,'."'B'".');" > ';
```

Comment: thx for the reply, but it invoke this :syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention i'm using concatenation assignment like my edited post up there